# $[F(a):F]<\infty \implies a$ algebraic over F

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $E/F$ be an extention field and $a\in E$. We want to show that 
$$[F(a):F]<\infty \implies a\text{ algebraic over } F$$
without the theorem which tells us that every finite extension is algebraic.

*Proof.*  Let $[F(a):F]<\infty$. If $a\in E$ was transcendental over $F$, then $F(a)\cong F(x)$. But, we know that $[F(x):F]=\infty$. So, $[F(a):F]=\infty$, contradiction.

Is this proof correct?

Thank you

Comment: What is $F(x)$ in your proof?

Comment: The field of rational funtions with coefficients over $F$. In other words, it ts the fraction field $Q(F[x])$ of the polynomial ring $F[x]$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$[F(a) : F] = n< \infty \implies \exists \{\lambda_0, ...,\lambda_n\}: \sum_0^n\lambda_ia^i = 0$ $(n+1$ elements can't be linearly independent).

So there exists a polynomial of degree $n$, with root $a$. Hence $a$ is algebraic.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Does thes come from the theorem that every set (subset of $F(a)$) with $>n$ elements is linearly dependent?

Comment: If it happens that $\lambda_n = 0$ then the polynomial has smaller degree.

Comment: @Chris $[F(a) : F]$ is an $n$-dimensional vector with coefficients in $F$. Since it is $n$-dimensional, any $n+1$ vectors have to be linearly dependent.

Comment: But how do we know that all the n+1 elements are distinct here ? Without being distinct we cannot have them linearly dependent.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes it's possible to find such polynomials. My question was about the fact that is it always possible that we have these elements distinct. I mean in case of a general extension E|F it is not always possible and we can find polynomial that has a zero as you suggested, but for the extension F(a)|F , I was curious, **as many proof that I have seen about F(a) this possibility of not being distinct is often excluded.**

Comment: @Asminum: if any two of the elements $a^i, i=0,1,\dots,n$ are equal then we already have a polynomial equation whose root is $a$. So this case is simpler.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes indeed! Consider an alternate idea since each $λ_i$ belongs to $F(a)$ then everyone one of them can be uniquely expressed as the elements of basis of vector space $F(a)$ and that's why they are distinct. Is it wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking yes, although the claim to be proven is more basic than the fact that $[F(x):F]=\infty$, so you need to check that the proof of the latter doesn't make use of the fact that any finite extension is algebraic.

A much simpler and straightforward proof would be to use the dimension of the extension to prove there exists a polynomial $f\in F[x]$ with $f(a)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that $\langle a \rangle$ spans $F(a)$ (as an $F$-vector space):

Observe that $F(a)$ is singly generated over $F$.  In particular, $\{1, a, a^2, \dots\}$ is a spanning set of $F(a)$ (seen as an $F$-vector space).  Since $[F(a):F] = n < \infty$, there are $f_0, \dots, f_n \in F$ such that $$\sum_{i=0}^n f_i a^i = 0  \text{.}$$  I.e., $\{1, a, a^2, \dots, a^n\}$ is $F$-linearly dependent.  But this says $a$ is a root of a degree $n$ polynomial with coefficients in $F$, so $a$ is algebraic over $F$.

If you do not know that $\langle a \rangle$ spans $F(a)$ (as an $F$-vector space):

Since $[F(a):F] = n < \infty$, $F(a)$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$.  Then $\{1, a, a^2, \dots, a^n\}$ is a list of $n+1$ elements of this vector space, so is $F$-linearly dependent.  I.e., there are $f_0, \dots, f_n \in F$ such that $$\sum_{i=0}^n f_i a^i = 0  \text{.}$$  But this says $a$ is a root of a degree $n$ polynomial with coefficients in $F$, so $a$ is algebraic over $F$.